# How should I react to those who write answers demeaning Lord Shiva and his family?

Tags: discussion, suggestions

First of all, I don't hate any God, whoever it is Vishnu or Shiva or Krishna. I respect Vishnu (especially Lord Venkateswara of Tirupati) as much as Shiva, but I like Shiva more when compared to other Gods. I'm neither a Shaivaite nor Vaishnavaite by birth rather my family worships a Grama Devata which comes under Shaktism.

I often get offended when some users demean Lord Shiva and his family. I know Hinduism has many schools and Shaivism, Vaishnavism and Shaktism are different sects who believe their respective Gods as Supreme. There's no wrong in believing your favorite God as Supreme but some users deliberately censure or demean Shiva and Shiva Purana. They reject entire Shiva Purana citing it as "pool of interpolations". I don't bother whether they believe Shiva Purana or not but they write these kind of statements in their answers. New users are being misled and brainwashed with their statements, which I feel it as unscrupulous.

Additionally, I request everyone to write their respective perspectives before answering these kind of questions. There are many answers on this site which say "Vishnu is Supreme" overtly without citing perspective. Also, a user of this site overtly claims "Lord Vishnu is Supreme" by citing some unreliable blogs. As most of users on this site are Vaishnavaites, these issues don't capture attention of most of the users.

How should I react to these situations or in general, how should people react when someone offends their faith? Again, I request everyone to include perspective or scripture (either Vaishnava or Shiva), which says their respective Gods as Supreme. Also, I request moderator to make a mandatory rule to include perspective or School of thought in their answers.

Comment: Can you present some cases?

Comment: @AnkitSharma i deliberately skipped cases as this would offend some users.

Comment: Offensive can very person to person. So atleast i can't say anything till i know what exactly happened.

Comment: @AnkitSharma This is just one example, see this [example](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5327/3500). There are many such things. i don't want to name all.

Comment: [If you don't like something...](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/m/mayaangelo101310.html)

Comment: I've written one [Note](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/conversation/note) as a suggestion for similar/related purpose.

Comment: @Pandya Like I said earlier, who would visit a chatroom to see a bookmarked conversation? Make a meta post on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anil, I sympathise and support your asking for a rule to label one's answers as derived from a particular school of thought.

It is indeed sad that matters related to Siva are dismissed as interpolations.

As for how to react:-

1. Remind yourself that such statements are false. While it is okay to hold one's favorite deity as supreme, it is incorrect to denounce others and is tantamount to daiva dooshana. Let those indulging in this activity reap the fruits of such negative actions all by themselves.
2. Having said that, sometimes, dharmaagraham and satyaagraham are called for. One must voice one's protest; especially when truth is in danger of being distorted and falsehoods get passed on. Sectarian fundamentalism is not dissimilar to Macaulay and others bad-mouthing ,denigrating and denuding Hinduism in order to weaken Hindus and establish the Englishman's superiority  over Indians. The Englishman knew that his own faith and philosophy were inferior in comparison and the only way to establish his superiority was by undermining our faith.

To such sectarian fundamentalists  say "That is your opinion alone. You may say Vishnu is supreme because you are a vaishnavite but you do not have the right to say Shiva is inferior. It not only violates scripture but is intellectually dishonest. Why is Vishnu called  "sarva, siva, sthANU" and other shiva names in the sahasranama if Shiva is inferior?"

Also scripture says "sivascha hrdayam vishnuh, vishnoscha hrdayam sivah".

You can quote these statements and many others from scripture when countering the arguments you cite in your question.

Essentially people who are incapable of seeing equivalence in Shiva and Vishnu are unfamiliar with scripture.

3. Use the tools provided by the site, viz, flag , close, call for moderator's attention, downvote etc.

It is tragic that Hindus need to be fighting amongst themselves when there are external forces constantly working to eradicate Hindu faith and astitva

Answer (score -1):

> Iswarasya prashamsAyAm na sukham nindAyAm vA na dukkham sukha dukha
>   rahitatvAt, kintu nindakasya narakameva ||
>
> .......
>
> The Iswara or God is neither pleased by his praise nor offended by
>   criticism as he is beyond happy-sad like states. But the censurer
>   definitely gets Hells.

Now, the persons who have gone down to the extent of demeaning Gods are surely sinners. So, why would you even want to interact with them (by reacting to their posts unless you are refuting some of their claims)?

Anyone, who is concerned about his own spiritual (and material) good, should not only shun sinful acts but the sinful persons are to be shunned as well.

Because associating with sinners is equally a sin.

> THE destroyer of a Brahmanas, one who drinks spirituous liquors, a
>   thief, and the violator of the preceptor's bed, **and the one who
>   associates with them, are the great sinners,**
>
> Usana Smriti, Chapter 8, Verse 1.

So, IMO, you should shun all kinds of interactions with them and if that is not possible, ignore them (and the posts) as much as possible. Also, please do not get hurt or sad upon seeing such posts because it is not worth it.

You can still moderate by keeping interactions to the minimum. That's something personal and i think you can easily deal with it.

*NOTE- The following are the grievances that i have addressed in the answer. Because, i don't really think that you are seeking advice (which are rules or community guidelines related)
 as a moderator. Because if such posts are violating site policies you very well know how to deal with it being a moderator. Now, if it is not violating rules but still demeaning Gods then my advice would be as suggested above.*

1) I often get offended when some users demean Lord Shiva and his family.-How to deal with it?
2) how should people react when someone offends their faith?
3) How should I react to those who write answers demeaning Lord Shiva and his family?

Comment: How is not interacting a solution? Where is tolerance or community spirit?  Do you realise that you are addressing a post of a moderator? You are saying a _moderator_ not to speak to a group of users. That is totally against the spirit of community and moderation. We are interested in the content and not in the user.

Comment: 1) How is not interacting a solution?---- That it is not, The Destroyer himself can confirm. I don't need to say much on the issue. He has interacted enough to know. 2) Do you realise that you are addressing a post of a moderator? You are saying a moderator not to speak to a group of users.--- Yeah why shudn't i? But the post was made by OP when he was not a MOD. That has to be taken into account too besides taking into account the fact that the OP is now a MOD. @NogShine

Comment: **   Just because he is a MOD don't expect me to advise him to interact with the sinners. Also, since i realize entirely shunning all kinds of associations is not possible so i have these lines in my answer " and if that is not possible, ignore them (and the posts) as much as possible" @NogShine

Comment: Even though he asked the question as a normal user, He is a mod now. A user should not judge a post by the author of the post. He should see all the posts on the site because he is the moderator of the whole site. So, your suggestion is invalid. Possible or not possible is secondary. One should not ignore posts of a group of users when they are part of site especially a moderator because he should moderate them as well. It is against the policy. You should have suggested to ignore the content if that is offensive rather than users or their posts. Just my opinion.

Comment: He should see all the posts on the site because he is the moderator of the whole site. So, your suggestion is invalid---- He can still see all the posts but interacting is not always necessary. He can use other tools that a MOD has wisely to deal with the situation because as my answer says it's sinful to associate with sinners. I have given my suggestion, now it's upto to OP to decide what to do with it. Also when you think that my answer is bad just Dv and move on. @NogShine

Comment: @NogShine It is not necessary that a post which is demeaning Gods is violating site rules. So, in those cases there is no need for Destroyer to interact to with the users. Now, if such posts are against rules, then Destroyer very well knows how to deal with them. So my suggestion is quite valid because i don't think there's a rule which forces users to interact with all users. It is simply a matter of personal choice.

Comment: There's no rule that one should interact but there is a strict rule (which everyone  knows I suppose)  that one should not ignore their posts based on their beliefs or faiths. Content stays even the user is deleted.  We are interested in the content of the users. Also, you can't label a group of users as sinners. The question is about answers and not about a group of users.

Comment: I can ignore any posts based on whatever..Why should i be forced to read all posts here? I will decide what to and what not to read..Can you show me that rule? i myself do not read all posts..There are many posts which have not read. @NogShine