# is denigration of Hindu scripture allowed just because it appears in other hindu-scriptures?

Tags: discussion

"Among these puranas Satvika Puranas lead one to liberation, Rajasa do not cause good and tamasa puranas lead one to hell." (236.2)

vishnuists bring this up again and again and again and there cannot be any doubt that this is in scriptures due to sectarian hatred.  A near and dear relative no longer alive read the Siva purana every day and posts like this are implying he went to hell.

All kinds of trivialities are censored but these monstrously hateful statements are allowed because "scripture" says it.

This should be changed.

Comment: Avoiding such denigration is already discussed at [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1033/277) and [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1122/277).

Comment: not so.  You are taking about denigration by posters.  I am talking about past sectarian hatreds frozen into scriptures that people are citing , that too again and again and again and again.

Comment: However it mostly depends upon how such verses are interpreted.

Comment: what is there to interpret in "tamasa puranas lead to hell"?

Comment: "there cannot be any doubt that this is in scriptures due to sectarian hatred" do you mean interpolation?

Comment: "interpolation" is a meaningless term.  all puranic material was added to and edited over centuries.  the ebb and flow of sectarian relations must have inserted the hateful material when the rivalries were serious.

Comment: @Pandya why are you struggling to understand the simple sentence? He is just asking whether denigration of other scriptures (like Shiva Purans by Padma Puran) is allowed just because it's denigration by scripture? You can't escape merely saying - " However it mostly depends upon how such verses are interpreted."

Comment: SK, Rivalry has always been there. There are so many scriptures, we can't eliminate all.

Comment: but vaishnavites on this board have belabored "tamasic puranas" ad nauseum.  OK we got it - surely if you have said it 20 times it is enough? @rohith

Comment: Didn't get you. @SK - surely if you have said it 20 times it is enough?

Comment: I want them to move on not be like a stuck needle.

Comment: When there was a similar discussion in the past about stopping some verses of smritis, it was agreed that since it is a scripture it will be allowed. Some people's interests will not be the site's policy. So, the same applies here also. The site is not partial to any sect. (that is what I think). There are no Vishnuists. Don't propose wrong terms.