# Can we have agreed-upon rules for the apparently unstoppable war going on here?

Tags: discussion

"Every word in scripture is literally true down to the last letter" versus "scripture has to be reinterpreted for modern times".

can we reduce the personal animus - after all we are reacting to bits and bytes wafting over the 'net.

Comment: You can do anything you want here as long as you're following the rules of SE .. and there is no need for any other rules.

Comment: Yes, just as some others are willing to be subjected to attacks against orthodoxy from "you know who"

Comment: By the way, in any case [this would be useful](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1122/277) for everyone to keep in mind while framing question as concluded [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1600/277) also.

Answer (score 3):

I agree. I don't have much to say on this but to keep those wars limited to ourselves as they are opinion based and are against growing as a community.

Just pointing out some other thing which I think (*from previous discussions*) many community members are still finding hard to digest even though it is [accepted community rule](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1727/93).

#### Words to avoid while interacting/discussing with community members

It is unjust to represent someone or a group of people with words formed on religious grounds. This site deals with Hinduism that doesn't mean we can change the SE policy to introduce religious practices

From [be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) page of Stackexchange:

> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.

Let's keep religious references limited to the posts on this site.

Note: To keep in other words, it is fine to use the religious words/references in posts but not fine if **we** use them to describe a person or a group of people **on this site**.

Comment: I find it strange that in para one you agree with OP. And then you go onto cite the policy which OP has been regularly flouting in several posts including this question

Comment: I might have missed the flouting in this question which I can't see.

Comment: Using quotes for "the sect" , and then adding everybody knows which sect is being referred seems to fall into the category of alienating a certain group of people based on their religious beliefs .

Comment: What I understood is - people should avoid sect wars.

Comment: If only it was paraphrased that way.

Comment: In my opinion, it will never happen.  The undercurrent cold war will go on.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv please explain. If possible post it as answer so we know your opinion. I feel people avoid posting it because of negative votes which we should not care and just be happy that one posted their opinion.

Comment: I am not bothered about negative voting.  And, at the same time not interested to post again and again same opinion.  My earlier posts in Meta are self explanatory. @Mr_Green Sooner or Later the site is going to wind up due to immature acts of a few members, belonging to ONE sect

Comment: I am still continuing this site because occasionally I have been coming across some brilliant questions/answers and it's through those brilliant questions/answers, I have been learning something. That is all. @Mr_Green

Comment: If my assessment is correct, 2 out of 3 moderators belong to the same dominant Sect of this site. What solace can be expected from them? Their pampering of the members of their sect and step motherly attitude towards others is very much evident. I will Stop here @Mr_Green

Comment: I am not much sure of the comments above but clearly there is some dispute regarding sects which must be stopped as there won't be any possible outcome of it. It is better to discuss here by each person as answer so we can understand each other and try to come up with a solution. What happening currently is bad for you (unnecessary stress) and for this site as well.

Comment: "We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion" Virtually anyone can get offended by anything. If I write some of the comments made by Shankara on buddhists, then the latter are certain to get offended. How to ensure no one is offended?

Comment: @SK I treat farewell messages with skepticism.

Comment: @yAdRcchika by being polite. If you are discussing something that is fine but you are pointing someone, that is not. Even if you are trading carefully and still if someone feels offended, they will flag which will be approved only if it is valid. This is quite fine.