# Why my comment was deleted?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I posted two comments. I usually take snapshots while commenting to keep record of my comments which are worthy. Both got deleted. But I'm interested to know the reason why my below comment was deleted [under this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26587/8696)?

> Keshav I don't like your brackets. And you are very much non authority to me in Shiva related works. You don't need to keep burden of authentication. Let it be left to me alone. Btw, yes he might not literally laugh. :)

And the reply was

> @Rohit. I deleted it because it ran afoul of the [Be Nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Can anyone tell me how it is against the be nice policy? Or why it got deleted? Can the act of deletion be justified?

Comment: I am surprised that it isn't restored yet.. it's easy here coz this was clearly another instance of wrong moderation.

Comment: @Rickross Good moderation is lacking here it seems. there are 3 moderators none has interacted with this thread so far. at least my comment should be restored with edit. I need to ask something on main meta then.

Comment: Actually the core issue here is what triggered ur "angry" reaction (i don't agree that it was rude in any way).. and this is already discussed very well in the post by Tezz linked in my answer.. People agree there that one should not be allowed to make comments like "which isn't considered an authentic work" completely unwantedly..bUt none to stop those users ..they are still doing the same even now.. and some angry reactions are bound to come because we also are human beings.. Even Tezz, who is otherwise very polite, had to react angrily in his post.

Comment: @Rickross What should we do when any particular mod stops listens community and starts acting as per own will?

Comment: I don't know.. let's see what other mods have to say.. it is already clear that adding such unwanted notices to whatever is not welcome. They should be removed.

Comment: Even one of my sarcastic comments on S K's posts got deleted. I think the site's Be Nice policy needs to upgraded.

Comment: @Rohit That portion in the brackets has now been removed. You can edit the question and update it.

Comment: @Rickross Edit as you wish. I am not good at filtering. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break your comment into parts.

> Keshav I don't like your brackets. And you are very much non authority
>   to me in Shiva related works. You don't need to keep burden of
>   authentication. Let it be left to me alone. Btw, yes he might not
>   literally laugh. :)

- Keshav I don't like your brackets.-- This portion is not rude.

  - And you are very much non authority
    to me in Shiva related works. --- This might look as a personal and as a somewhat aggressive comment. So, let it stay deleted.
- You don't need to keep burden of
  authentication. Let it be left to me alone --- This portion also is not rude to me. Taking into account the comment which you were replying to.
- Btw, yes he might not literally laugh. :) -- And obviously this is not rude at all.

So, ideally, instead of deleting the whole comment, the comment should have been kept after editing the "rude" portions out of it.

**The deletion of the whole comment was not the right thing done.**

Also, in such situations, i guess, a lot depends on the moderator's discretion. One mod deleted it but any other might not have.

But you also made some mistakes.

One should not react to each such comments by a posting question in return. One should ignore such comments completely which are not adding any value to the post.

Let's see the comment you replied to.

> I think what the Kalabhairavashtakam (which isn't considered an
>   authentic work of Adi Shankaracharya) is saying is that Kala
>   Bhairava's laugh is powerful enough to destroy everything in the
>   Universe, not that he actually uses his laugh for this purpose.

This whole comment is relevant to the post except the part which is in the brackets. That part was not asking for clarification. Was not about something that you wanted to know in your question. So, it is not adding any value to the post.

Thus, your 2nd mistake was to flag it as "rude". It was not rude but was "no longer needed". At least, the part in the brackets was exactly that. So, flag it properly now and try to get that part deleted.

Actually, the core topic here, and which is about adding just unwanted passages like " this text is interpolated/not authentic" in posts/comments to demean some other sects' beliefs or for any other reasons, have already been criticised and discussed very well [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/when-is-it-acceptable-to-caution-the-reader-of-disputes-as-to-the-origin-of-a-te/1011#1011).

So the sad thing is, people who were doing it, inspite of being criticised, are still doing the same even now.

And I don't really know who can stop them if not the moderators?

Comment: Good introspection. I'm flagging the comment now. Let's see what happens. And yes the site being inactive in moderation like Mythology tag also is there along with the same activity of the moderator. Need to think on this.

Comment: @Rickross Yes , i like your style of this answer especially on META. Keep it up. I am not very good over here , but will certainly try my best here also.

Comment: haha ok.. i will try to maintain this style @SwiftPushkar

Comment: [Drop “not constructive”, combine “noisy”, reword “rude” and “other” comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292011/357396). You need to know what are comment flags. That comment doesn't qualify as no longer needed also. It should be only used when whole part is unnecessary or chatty. Moderators won't edit user's opinions. It is censoring people's voice. They only remove rude parts. There is nothing rude in the said comment just his opinion. For partial removing, you should use custom flag. NLN is wrong flag again.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking a *specific user not* to comment or not to answer about this specific topic by saying he is non authority to you because of some personal reason or opinion difference. You should not ask a user or group of users to refrain from answering or commenting because you know what they will say. You have no right to do so.

Telling someone that they are unimportant to you or not care about what they say is being impolite and it is against Be Nice policy.

> Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts.

On the site, anyone can ask and anyone can answer. User is not important. Content is important. This is not a place for personal grudges. I have asked a question similar to this [on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294985/357396). The answer I got says

> Similarly, *asking a user not to contribute in a comment, will just result in the comment getting flagged and removed*.

Closest thing you can do is ignore if you don't like the comment. If their answer is not useful, it should be ignored and downvoted. Asking a specific user not to comment or answer to your post because you don't like something about them is wrong.

Hence, the comment deletion is justified.

Comment: True! Ignorance is only thing we should come up with on this site.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto What do you mean?

Comment: I am referring to last paragraph of your answer.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I clarified what I meant to say. On questions and answers, we should not say a user should not write comment, "I don't like your <something>, you are no one to me" etc., Even in chat, we can ignore them but saying something personal is wrong.

Comment: He called it inauthentic which I also found rude being a devotee? What to do? He is certainly not authority to me but where have I asked him to refrain from commenting? Nor it is personal attack, content with his name was needed for plot only. My titles & details are ended with asking activity of deletion rather than cornering individual guy so it is post focussed. You wrote anything and ended with **Hence, the comment deletion is justified**.

Comment: Calling a work is just "inauthentic" is not rude. It is his opinion. He said Adi Shankara might have not written the work. He didn't say anything rude against the work itself. Saying "_you_ are very much non authority to me" is personal and it implies that you don't want to listen to him because you don't like what he said based on opinion difference. I am talking about comment not about your question. I wrote very much related post from MSE where a user here wrote "XYZ sect don't answer the question. I know what you say". You are also saying similar thing.

Comment: I think better the concerned person should post clarification. We dont need proxies. Do we ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Acc. to your logic, if it may so be called, Rohit alone should take care of the responding going forward and Rickross' answer is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Because we.can only assume what were his reasons for.doing so. Without knowing it its hard to support such point. I have seen many such posts in support. So it was my gwneral opinion.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi This question is posted on meta. So, anyone can answer and give relavant opinions if it is right or wrong. The OP himself asked it in the question. The moderator clarified already the reason that it is deleted because it is against the Be Nice policy. So, it was already clarified. Question again is pointless. If me answering is proxy, what do you call of other answer?