# What posts/comments fall under bigotry of any kind?

Tags: discussion

According to the [Be nice policy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice):

> Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)

I have recently flagged a comment that was saying:

> You can't. Except for realized souls, Caste is the very core of Hinduism - **the Brahmins even inserted a discriminatory verse into the Purusha Sukta of Rig Veda**. If Caste goes away, Hinduism will go away.

But it was declined. I am not sure why it was declined?

Comment: There is no clear policy on bigotry on this site. It's entirely up to to the mod handling the comment. You can even choose to alienate 'foreigners', 'westerners' (because majority of Hindus are natives of India), 'indologists', 'western indologists', 'homosexuals', 'wendy doniger and her friends', 'BORI scholars', so I guess mods can't be selective about bigotry...so good that your flag was rejected.

Comment: The part of comment emphasized is removed since it was claiming the interpolation and bit offensive.

Comment: @Pandya what about the comment discussed in [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/why-my-comment-was-deleted) post then? There also problem was created only because certain user claimed interpolation.

Comment: @Rickross The brackets claiming interpolation is already removed.

Comment: Oh that's great @Pandya