# Why are HSE guidelines on citable material being applied inconsistently?

Tags: support

One of the guidelines is that only scriptural sources and modern Acharyas like Vivekananda, Ramana Maharishi et al are acceptable.

And yet in [Why was Surya killed by Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3704/why-was-surya-killed-by-lord-shiva), the following material appears:

> One note of caution: references to Ganesha in ancient Hindu scripture are few and far between, since Ganesha only rose to popularity later on, so there is a possibility that this may be an interpolation in the Brahma Vaivarta Purana. (I raise a similar issue in my answer here concerning a passage in the Shiva Purana.)

The poster HIMSEF says what the source of his opinion is:

> @Tezz No, it's not just my belief, it's the **considered conclusion of scholars** based on things like style of languages in different passages of Puranas, discrepancies of manuscripts etc. It's universally agreed by scholars that Ganesha was not that popular in ancient times, and that it's only relatively recently that he became more popular. –
> Keshav Srinivasan
> ♦
> Jun 17, 2016 at 7:15

Scholarly material not backed up by direct scriptural citation is deleted by the mods ALL THE TIME - why was my flag to delete this material declined?

Site participation seems low by historical standards - it doesn't help that moderator actions are not being seen as consistent.

Comment: Such notes of caution are to be removed .. we already decided on this long back (https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1010)

Comment: I am not asking for a note of caution - I am asking for secular, scholarly material not backed by scripture to be DELETED - as was done with DOZENS of ENTIRE posts, the result of painstaking research, from another poster.  To allow this material to stand is an arbitrary exercise of power. @rickross .  perhaps Rubilette yakshi's suggestion that mods be replaced by AI would lead to more fairness.

Comment: Ok you've a point but first I would like to see that note edited out from the post

Comment: no note.  I deleted the secular material with an edit note "secular material not allowed under HSE rules".  Another user put it back, with some name-calling of me.  I flagged the name-calling and the mods declined that flag. @rickross

Comment: Yes I can see that from the revisions .. instead of editing that part out yourself you should have flagged for Mods to do the edit .. if that was done the current situation could have been avoided .. user would not have rollbacked an edit made by a Mod.

Comment: There is no rule that edits have to be cleared by mods _ I have made any number of edits of other users' posts.  This user who reversed my edit (while calling me a name) CONSTANTLY baits me and I can never be sure mods would act fairly when I complain about this user. @rickross .  I don't expect anything to be done - the tone that was set for HSE at the inception is still largely intact.,

Comment: Every one of us must have edited other users' posts on many occasions but to improve the posts or to make some corrections .. in the name of edits we can not simply remove statements made by the author from posts. If the statements are problematic for some reasons then flagging them for mods is the way .. otherwise there can be edit wars.

Comment: OK $rickross - this is my last comment.  It cannot be clearer that this material must be deleted.  But it won't be deleted.  as they said in some movie "I need to learn to live with disappointment".

Comment: @Rickross - Re your last comment, 'we can not simply remove statements made by the author,' what is your opinion on [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/21817/3) edit?

Comment: We can't remove in that manner .. same is done here too (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/56053/revisions) @CDR